# Combobox Selected Value going "null" on GridView_CellClick Event

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am using Winforms with C# and I am getting this result.

I have a gridview where some data are loaded and in cell click event, the data is displayed on text boxes and combobox, however, one of the combobox has gone crazy and not displaying the data on select. When debugging the code, the SelectedValue goes to null while on other combo boxes, the value changes.

Below are the codes used.

**Gridview cell click event**

```
if (e.RowIndex != -1)
 {
   DataGridViewRow grid = stockGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
   txtStockId.Text = grid.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
   txtBarcode.Text = grid.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   cmbQtyDescId.SelectedValue = grid.Cells[2].Value;
   txtQtyDesc.Text = grid.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
   txtBrandName.Text = grid.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
   txtProductName.Text = grid.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
   txtUnitPrice.Text = grid.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
   txtRetailPrice.Text = grid.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
   txtStockInHand.Text = grid.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
   cmbCategory.SelectedValue = grid.Cells[9].Value;
   cmbSupplier.SelectedValue = grid.Cells[10].Value;
   chkIsTaxable.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(grid.Cells[11].Value);
  }
```

**Populate Combobox.** **For the other combo boxes, I am using the same code**

```
public static void FillCombo(List<QuantityDescriptionModel> quantityDescriptions, ComboBox control)
  {
   control.DataSource = quantityDescriptions;
   control.ValueMember = "Id";
   control.DisplayMember = "QtyDescription";
  }
```

**Screenshots attached**
[Data not loaded on cell_click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSSz1.png)
[Data loaded without cell_click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3dqZ.png)

Comment: You're setting the ComboBox value to a single value which doesn't have an associated `DisplayMember` path. What is the type of `quantityDescriptions`?

Comment: public class QuantityDescriptionModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string QtyDescription { get; set; }
    }

using just normal property
@WSC

Comment: I think you need to do something like: `cmbQtyDescId.SelectedItem = quantityDescriptions.Where(x => x.Id == grid.Cells[2].Value).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Are you sure that the data presented in the DataGridView at Column 2 is of type string? Have you tried to cast it? Btw, you should use databinding to automate the whole thing.

Comment: that worked like a charm just I had to add ToString(). But my questing is why the other are working normal and this became abnormal. Thanks

Comment: The other Columns (`Category` and `Supplier`) all seem to be of the same type, `string` on both ends. -- Use databadings. You can bind the SelectedValue property of the ComboBoxes to the corresponding Columns of the datasource of your DataGridView: it all becomes automatic (if you respect the data type)